# How to only obfuscate method name with Dotfuscator?

Tags: obfuscation, dotfuscator

Due to some reflection actions, I have the need to exclude some methods from **Dotfuscator ce** obfuscation:

```
[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
internal MyMethod (String input1)
{
   string member1 = "hello"
   string member2 = "world"
   [...]
}
```

The `Obfuscation` attribute does this job, but now also the complete content of the method is not obfuscated any more. How I can achieve that the name `MyMethod` will not be obfuscated, but the members `member1`, `member2` etc are still obfuscated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Note*: I work on the Dotfuscator team and am answering in that capacity.)

The names of local variables (what you refer to as "members") are stored with other debugging information in the Program Database (`.pdb`) file, not the assembly (`.dll` or `.exe` file). Dotfuscator renames code items in the assembly, but doesn't rename local variables in the `.pdb`.

We assume that customers concerned about reverse engineering aren't going to ship the `.pdb`, as it contains line number and source file information, which would make the reverse engineering process easy, even with an obfuscated assembly.

However, Dotfuscator can still produce `.pdb` files for internal testing and debugging.
If you'd like Dotfuscator Community (formerly known as Dotfuscator CE) to stop doing so, open your config file in Dotfuscator's user interface, go to *Settings* -> *General* and uncheck *Emit debugging symbols*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I was not aware of that the local var names are only present in the pdb. Of course I will not ship the pdb to the productive environement, but was wondering about the local var names while I debugged dotfuscated code (with "emit debugging symbols" activated). So everything is fine, thanks again.